# Issue with Kafka WordCount

Tags: apache-kafka-streams

Hi I'am trying to run the basic Kafka word count problem , the issue is the count(value) is not getting printed on console

```
KStream<String, String> textLines = builder.stream("word-count-input");
      KTable<String, Long> wordCounts = textLines

              .mapValues(textLine -> textLine.toLowerCase())
              .mapValues(String::toLowerCase)
              .flatMapValues(textLine -> Arrays.asList(textLine.split("\\W+")))
              .selectKey((key, word) -> word)
              .groupByKey()
              .count("Counts");

      wordCounts.to(Serdes.String(), Serdes.Long(), "word-count-output");
```

Console producer :

```
bin/kafka-console-producer.sh  --broker-list localhost:9092  --topic word-count-input
```

Console consumer :

```
bin/kafka-console-consumer.sh --bootstrap-server localhost:9092 --topic word-count-output --from-beginning --formatter kafka.tools.DefaultMessageFormatter --property print.key=true --property print.value=true --property key.deserailizer=org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringDeserializer -propertykey.deserailizer=org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.LongDeserialzer
```

However in the output I'm not getting the count for the input

Input :

```
This is Kafka
Kafka is awesome
Kafka Kafka Kafka
```

Expected Output

```
this 1
is 1
kafka 1
kafka 2
is 2
awesome 1
kafka 3
kafka 4
```

Actual Output

```
this 
is 
kafka 
kafka 
is 
awesome 
kafka 
kafka
```

Answer (score 2):

You have typos key.deserailizer and value.deserailizer in your console consumer command.

Comment: @user2834137 You should mark the answer as "accepted" if it solved the problem (and maybe upvote, too).